# Changes not visible when not logged in

Tags: plugins, cache, plugin-wp-supercache

I have a wordpress site and 4 hours ago I have made some changes to the home page and an internal page.

The changes I can see when I am logged in. When I try to log out, I only see the old pages and not the updated pages.

I've tried everything:

Total cleaning of the WP Super Cache
Manual cache cleanup
Disabling all cache of wordpress
Browser cache cleaning
None of these attempts worked. My version is 5.2.4.

What could be the problem? Why does Word Press have this cache issue?

Thanks for any help

Comment: The situation described in the title of this question conflicts with that described in the body. Consider filing an [edit] to make it more clear if your changes are only visible when logged in, or when logged out. That said, it does indeed sound like the product of a third-party caching mechanism. If clearing your caching plugin, CDN, and browser's caches has not resolved the issue, you may need to deactivate each plugin one at a time and test for changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove all the revisions from the edited page in admin panel.
You can find the revisions in right sidebar.

And you can disable the revisions by using config.php by putting this
`define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false);`.

And also you can delete from database using SQL query `DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "revision";`

Hope it will works.

Comment: That's an interesting solution! Are you implying that while logged in they might be seeing a preview of a draft, but when logged out they see the published version, or is there some behavior where revisions might conflict with a cache or something?